# SQL query to insert binary data using Ruby

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby

I'm trying to insert some binary data into database using 'mysql' gem in ruby. But as the binary data contains many single and double quotes, the following code fails. Please help me to fix it.

```
m = mysql.prepare("insert into data (binary) values ('#{binary_data}') ")
```

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.......' at line 1 (Mysql::Error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using prepared statements wrong. What about this?

```
stmnt = mysql.prepare("insert into data (`binary`) values (?)")
stmnt.execute binary
```

Answer (score 2):

**binary** is [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) in mysql so wrap it with apostrophe like

```
insert into data (`binary`) ......
```